# Meaning of phrase "Meet your bogie"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Google does not really show anything re meaning of this phrase:

> I always ask this question of the measurement advocates: "If you're so
>   enamored with measuring people why don't you tell them you'll let them
>   go home when they meet their bogie?" Most people would be home by 2:00
>   P.M. in a normal workday. 
>   -Stratton

Source: https://www.quality-assurance-solutions.com/Deming-Point-11.html

What does "meet their bogie" really mean?

Comment: Try looking up "bogey".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to try take a stab at this. That website deals with business management. The quote itself apparently comes from a person called Stratton. I don't know who he is, but they do mention William Edwards Deming, who was management consultant.

The quote is supposed to be a criticism of the management method of measuring success or efficiency by production quotas (the so called 'measurement advocates').

Bogey is a common term in golf for being one shot over par (thanks JonLarby). But in some dictionaries I found the meaning of "a number of shots required".

> b. obsolete a standard score for a hole or course, regarded as one
>   that a good player should make.
>  Collins Dictionary

> b. Chiefly British The number of strokes that a good player is likely
>   to need to finish a golf hole or course.
>  American Heritage
>   Dictionary

[Sources](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bogey)

So I infer that "to meet their bogie" is an idiom or metaphor originating from golf which in this case means for a worker to meet their required production quota. When they do so they may go home at 2 o'clock.

I'm not a hundred percent about this analysis, but I figured I'd give it a shot.

Comment: I agree that he is probably using bogey in the old fashioned sense to mean once they've done all their work (par). However, bogey is commonly used in golf to denote shooting one **over** par, not one under.

Comment: @JonLarby Oh yeah, one under par is birdie, haha, I'm not a golf guy. Thanks.